# i cant access to user profile image even thaugh is exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping, jsx, server-side-rendering

when i `console.log(user)` it shows every thing i made in user model that suppose to appear even the profile avatar url is showing and when i `console.log(user.avatar)` the console giving me `undefined`

this is the mapping code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import Avatar from '../Avatar';

const Info = () => {
  const { id } = useParams()
  const { auth } = useSelector(state => state)
  
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    if(id === auth.user._id){
      setUserData(auth.user)
      // console.log(userData)
    }
  }, [id, auth.user])
  
  return (
    <div className='info'>
      {
        Object.values(userData).map((user) => {
          <div className="info_container" key={user._id}>
            <Avatar src={user.avatar} size="supper-avatar"/>
            console.log(user)
          </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Info
```

[image]

note: i made the avatar image url as a default value in the schema
i wrote Object.values to avoid `userData.map is not a function` error

Comment: When calling `setUserData(auth.user)` what is the value of `auth.user`?  Is it still an array as expected, or is it now an object?  If the latter then your use of `Object.values` isn't *avoiding* an error, it's *hiding* one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing up *objects* and *arrays*, and mis-using `Object.values` in order to try and avoid reconciling that mixup.

The first thing you need to do is decide if `userData` is an object or an array of objects.

**If it's an object**, don't initialize it to an array.  You can initialize it to `undefined`:

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState();
```

And conditionally display it only if/when it's defined:

```
<div className='info'>
  {userData ? 
    <div className="info_container" key={userData._id}>
      <Avatar src={userData.avatar} size="supper-avatar"/>
    </div> : null}
</div>
```

**If it's an array** then just use `.map()` on that array:

```
<div className='info'>
  {userData.map((user) => (
    <div className="info_container" key={user._id}>
      <Avatar src={user.avatar} size="supper-avatar"/>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

But don't initialize it to an array and then later update it to an object.  Because then you'll be going back-and-forth with different errors/bugs because your data structure keeps changing out from under the code using that data.